# Zend Framework 2 - Segment Route

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I'm building an app using Zend Framework v2.2.0 and I'm creating different modules for each section.

In a module, called `Company`, there is this route:

```
'company_wines' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:slug_company/:action/',
        'constraints'=>array(
            ':slug_company'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+',
            ':action'=>'(wines|red\-wines|white\-wines|sparkling\-wines|dessert\-wines|rose\-wines){1}',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Company\Controller\Company',
        ),
    ),
),
```

In another module, called `Vineyard`, I have this route:

```
'vineyard_page' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/vineyard/:slug_vineyard/',
        'constraints'=>array(
            ':slug_vineyard'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Vineyard\Controller\Vineyard',
            'action'     => 'vineyard',
        ),
    ),
),
```

When I test with url `domain.ext/Company-name/red-wines/` or `domain.ext/Company-name/white-wines` etc, the `Company` controller is invoked.

If I test with `domain.ext/vineyard/Vineyard-name/`, the `Vineyard` controller is not invoked, is still invoked the `Company` one and the error message say that the controller cannot dispatch the request. Off course there is no method called `VineyardnameAction()` in `CompanyController` class.

I was expecting that the route match against the list of values specified on regex for `:action`, also if the `:slug_company` regex match the "flag" `vineyard`, then there is no action that match the `Vineyard-name` part...

If I test the `:action` regex with `preg_match_all`, nothing is found in a string like `domain.ext/vineyard/Vineyard-name/`.

If I disable `Company` module or delete the the `company_wines` route, `vineyard` route is working.

I've solved creating different routes for each wines types, but I would like to understand whath I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
'constraints' => array(
    'slug_vineyard'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+',
),

'constraints'=>array(
    'slug_company'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+',
    'action'=>'(wines|red\-wines|white\-wines|sparkling\-wines|dessert\-wines|rose\-wines){1}',
),
```

remove the colon from the default / constraints section and it should work fine.

As you have put the colon in there the constraints aren't being forced so default constraints will be used, which ever route comes first will match.

Comment: Furthermore the order in which those routes are defined at config-level is important since the string `vineyard` also matched the regex for `slug_company`...

Comment: @sam you are right, but url and constraints should be evaluated entirely, right?

Comment: @Gabriel Router should return the first match that has no more child_routes. Other than that i don't really understand the question.